# How to pass login userid to all pages when i redirect to any page by clicking menu

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a customer module in asp.net website project. i developed login page and from login page i am entering to customer home page. here i am giving menu items like

1. customerprofile
   2.customerpurchased items
   3.customervieweditems
   4.customerbiilingpage like

here for every page i need used login id that should come directly in pageload.

please any one help me how to pass login user id to above 4 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into authentication for this site. Search on FormsAuthentication using a FormsAuthenticationTicket, or use the newer Memebership and Roles functionality. Do this properly and you really don't "pass" the login aroun, you read it from the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` container.

Answer (score 0):

why not you use Session ? Session is the best case for your scenario.  or if you wanted to use Authentication mechanism, then Go for Membership Provider, FormsAuthentication. [How To Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Session["UserID"]=yourUseID;
```

to retreive

```
var userID=Session["UserID"].ToStrin();
```

Comment: Thanx Ravi   for your solution